# What is Best Practice for running PHP in background?

Tags: bash, php, background-process

When running the following on the command line it will be suspended until I issue the fg command:

```
/usr/bin/php -r 'phpinfo();' &
```

This is the case regardless if the PHP code is contained in a file with a shebang of `#!/usr/bin/php`.

I am running CentOS and bash shell.

Comment: Works for me. The `&` puts it in the background, it doesn't get "suspended".

Answer (score 3):

There is no method specific to PHP when it comes to running jobs in the background. The widely accepted methods are:

1. Using a `screen`. Install `screen` (if it is not already installed), then run your PHP script under a screen. You can detach from the `screen` anytime and log out of the machine and the script will continue running. [Here](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/a-quick-tutorial-on-screen/) is one of the few hundred tutorials available online about how to use `screen`.
2. Using `nohup`. The usage is:

`nohup <yourPHPcommand> &`

The `nohup` will let your script 'say no' to the HANGUP signal when you log out, as a result, your PHP script will keep running even after you logout. The only problem is that you won't be able to bring that job/process to foreground and see the output(if it matters to you). You can redirect the output to a file and see what it is printing out from that file though.

Out of the above two, I recommend you use the `screen`. You can attach to the screen anytime you want and control the process the same way you would've if you had started in the foreground.

P.S:- Running the script with the ampersand (`&`) at the end does put it in the background, but the script/process gets killed when you log out of the terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I chose the nohup method because my scripts are batch style and are usually run from cron. All output is directed to a log file. On occasion the help desk will run them from the command line and will logout. The connection is sshd based and I have not observeed any process terminiation. Only the parent pid of the process changing to 1.

Comment: Note that `screen` isn't remotely the only tool to accomplish this task. Any terminal multiplexer will work (I prefer `tmux`).